# Why typescript treat a specific string as a string in class properties?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Here is the example:

```
type a = {
    b: '123'
}[]

class Test {
    public t:a = []
}


class SubTest extends Test {
    public t = [{
        b: '123' // error, Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"123"'
    }]
}
```

Is there a way to make `SubTest` passing typecheck without change `interface a`?

Comment: Why do you need to redeclare same member in derived class?

Comment: I edited the question and you can see that I want to assign to `t`

Comment: 123 is not a string but a static type. when you assign a value to type a, the Typescript compiler treats it to be a string because that is mutable. 123 is a special type and not a string, to tell the compiler that 123 is not going to change add as const, like b: 123 as const

Comment: This behavior of typescript is to avoid runtime errors

Comment: Just specify the type explicitly in derived class as well `public t: a` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhlC8UDeAoK6oCMBcUDkAjAEwDMeKAvgNoC6KKAxgDYwDOrUAKhK8MmhjABXTEwCWDKMFxxEtSvUYt2UAMojuvKBAAewCADsAJh019UGKMNESpMhFCoXLGHPmJkB6CnQpA

Answer (score 1):

add `as const`

```
class SubTest extends Test {
  public t = {
      b: '123'
  } as const
}
```

or

```
class SubTest extends Test {
  public t = {
      b: '123' as const
  }
}
```

this is also useful if you want to do things like derive a type from an array of strings, e.g.:

```
const x = ["foo", "bar"];
type tx = typeof x; // string[]

const y = ["foo", "bar"] as const;
type ty = typeof y; // readonly ["foo", "bar"]
```

Comment: It would got `'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type` when `type a = { b: '123 }[]`

Comment: @lastnigtic If I am understanding correctly you may want to use: `public t = [{ b: '123' as const }]`

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have property 't' in 'Test' you can not reassign it when extending. Change the property name in 'SubTest' to something other then 't' and it will work.

```
type a = {
  b: "123";
};

class Test {
  public t: a = {
    b: "123",
  };
}

class SubTest extends Test {
  public x: a = {
    b: "123",
  };
}
```

Comment: It works but this is the way I don't want to use.

Comment: then you need to clarify what exactly you want to acomplish